# Delete nodes with this same path and name

Tags: c#, xml

I created a treeview xml program that allows you to manage the tree xml. I need a program feature that will delete items by name and path.

For example:

```
    <Main>
<Set>
    <MId>1</MId>
    <RName>
        <MetaData>
            <PrdctName>
                Test 1
            </PrdctName>
        </MetaData>
    </RName>
</Set>
<Set/>
<Set/>
<Set>
    <MId>2</MId>
    <RName>
        <MetaData>
            <PrdctName>
                Test 1
            </PrdctName>
        </MetaData>
    </RName>
</Set>
</Main>
```

And i want to delete "PrdctName" in all xml-file by name and with this same path. Anyone can help me?

Edit: I try something like that but this doesnt work:

```
void deletebytag(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
    {
        List<TreeNode> nodee = new List<TreeNode>();

        foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
        {
            if (node.Name == "au_id")
            {
                nodee.Add(node);
            } 
            else
            {

                deletebytag(node.Nodes);

            }
        }
        foreach (TreeNode node in nodee)
        {
            nodes.Remove(node);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Like all list collection objects you need to remove from the last item to the first so the indexing doesn't get messed up.  I used xml Liinq below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication16
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<XElement> prdctNames = doc.Descendants("PrdctName").ToList();

            for (int i = prdctNames.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                prdctNames[i].Remove();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need a fuction and in my application i am using only XmlDocuments library

Comment: Linq XML is part of the Net Library and not a 3rd part application.  It is more efficient in enumerating through elements than the older xmlDocument library.